# What is the performance impact of 'logging enabled: true' in IISNode on Azure

Tags: node.js, performance, azure, logging, iisnode

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-nodejs-debug) states that it is possible to log the outputs of StdOut and StdErr streams to the file system.

What is the performance impact of doing this? Should I leave it on in production?

Answer (score 1):

As node.js application on Azure Web Apps is handled via iisnode module. And logging enable is only a functionality of iisnode which will have very little impact. As which also should to be a good method to trace error info in production env.

Meanwhile, it is recommended that we can [set up staging environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-staged-publishing) in your Web Apps, separate production and dev staging slot, if we need to use iisnode's troubleshooting configurations as document mentions at [Best practices and troubleshooting guide for node applications on Azure Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-nodejs-best-practices-and-troubleshoot-guide)